# Is it possible to collect an additional claim with the PhoneFactor-Verify or PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify technical profiles?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Starting from the custom policy starter pack, and the SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa example, I'd like to display an additional checkbox on the same screen where the user chooses "Send Code" or "Call Me".

I want the boolean value indicating if the user checked it to end up in a claim returned to the application.

Is this possible?

I've tried adding the custom claim as an `<OutputClaim>`, an `<InputClaim>` or both into the `PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify` technical profile. None of which had any effect in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, because both the **urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:multifactor:1.1.0** content definition and the **PhoneFactorProtocolProvider** profile type are specialized or fit-for-purpose for the multi-factor interaction.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it might be related to the page contract / content definition.